# Disabling comboboxes after a certain limit has been met

Tags: vba

I have 4 comboboxes called:

```
cboOption1 
cboOption2 
cboOption3 
cboOption4
```

Each of them can have one of 2 values, either 10 or 20 points, which the user selects from a drop down. However, the user can only select a maximum of 40 points across all drop downs, after which the remaining dropdowns that follow will be disabled.

**E.g.1**

```
cboOption1 = 20
cboOption2 = 20
```

Then

```
cboOption3.Enabled = False
cboOption3.Enabled = False
```

**E.g.2**

```
cboOption1 = 10
cboOption2 = 20
cboOption3 = 10
```

Then

```
cboOption4.Enabled = False
```

**E.g.3**

```
cboOption1 = 10
cboOption2 = 10
cboOption3 = 10
cboOption3 = 40
```

Then

```
None disabled
```

**My problem**

The difficulty I'm experiencing at the moment is figuring out how to flick the comboboxes on/off in response to user input. This is my code so far, it doesn't seem to be working too well, any idea how I can improve it.

**Code so far**

```
Sub checkTotal(var1, var2, var3, var4, total)
so1 = Int(var1)
so2 = Int(var2)
so3 = Int(var3)
so4 = Int(var4)
total = Nz(so1, 0) + Nz(so2, 0) + Nz(so3, 0) + Nz(so4, 0)

If total > 40 And (so1 = "20" Or so2 = "20" Or so3 = "20" Or so4 = "20") Then
   cboOption3.Value = ""
   cboOption3.Enabled = False
   cboOption4.Value = ""
   cboOption4.Enabled = False
End If

MsgBox total
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption1_Change()
Call checkTotal(cboOption1.Column(1), cboOption2.Column(1), cboOption3.Column(1), cboOption4.Column(1), so1RunningTotal)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption2_Change()
Call checkTotal(cboOption1.Column(1), cboOption2.Column(1), cboOption3.Column(1), cboOption4.Column(1), so1RunningTotal)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption3_Change()
Call checkTotal(cboOption1.Column(1), cboOption2.Column(1), cboOption3.Column(1), cboOption4.Column(1), so1RunningTotal)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOption4_Change()
Call checkTotal(cboOption1.Column(1), cboOption2.Column(1), cboOption3.Column(1), cboOption4.Column(1), so1RunningTotal)
End Sub
```

Comment: If each combobox can holds only 10 and 20, how is it possible to select 40 across the all drop downs? Do you have another combobox? BTW: Is it Access database?

Comment: `10 + 10 + 10 + 10`, or `10 + 10 + 20`, or `20 + 20`

Comment: As per your requirements, **cboOption1** and **cboOption2** should be always enabled and the state of **cboOption3** and **cboOption4** depends on values of **cboOption1** and **cboOption2**. Well... for the first time get the sum of **cboOption1** and **cboOption2** if it's less than 40, **cboOption3** should be enabled (add the value of **cboOption3**). If total is still less than 40, **cboOption4** should be enabled. It's easy to do. Think of it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read my comments to the question. I'd suggest to do that this way:

```
cboOption3.Enabled = CBool((cbo1Value + cbo2Value)<40)
cboOption4.Enabled = CBool((cbo1Value + cbo2Value + cbo3Value)<40)
```

Tip: use proper input parameters data type and remove **total** from input parameters.

```
Sub checkTotal(ByVal var1 As Integer, ByVal var2 As Integer, ByVal var3 As Integer, ByVal var4 As Integer)
```

See: [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

Comment: BTW: **CBool()** function in above example is not necessary. It has been added for better understanding...